# Where the itextpdf.jar library is?

Tags: itext

I have downloaded itext from here (https://github.com/itext/itextpdf) but I can't find any .jar file inside .zip. It says about Maven but I don't know much about Maven! I need to have the binary ready for use.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reporting this bug. Meanwhile the others have already helped you.

Comment: Please be aware that the two initial answer you received provide links to a version of iText that is no longer supported.

Comment: Strictly speaking the op gives hints that he might indeed mean the itext 5 in maintenance, not the current itext 7: he uses the [tag:itext] tag, not the [tag:itext7] tag, he talks about a single jar, and he references the itext 5 repositories.

Comment: Hi @mkl, since the OP doesn't have any jars yet, it is highly unlikely that the OP has already written any code. Even if the OP had, that code would never compile without the jars. Hence it is safe to assume that the OP is new to iText. Whoever is new to iText should start with the most recent version. I have no idea why someone would down-vote such an answer. It's just common sense

Comment: @BrunoLowagie *"I have no idea why someone would down-vote such an answer. It's just common sense"* - That downvote indeed does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find `itext` on Maven Central Repository.

At the moment, this is the latest version: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.13

From that page, just click the `jar` button and you will have your binary.

[image: Jar button]

Or you can access it directly from [this](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.13/itextpdf-5.5.13.jar) link.

*UPATE:*

5.x seems not to be the latest version, but 7.x (thanks @BrunoLowagie)

You can find the itext7 jars available here:

https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.itextpdf

Also, you can take a look on their official development documentation available [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java) on how to install it.
You have 2 options:

- if you need a separate jar and download it, you will have to go through each jar and download it.
- if you see yourself downloading manually to much, maybe it would be more advisable to make use of `Maven` and take `itext7-core` and that will download each of the jars from [here](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.itextpdf)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to downvote this answer. iText 5.5.13 is a *maintenance* release of the old iText 5 version. The most recent version is [iText 7.1.2](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.itextpdf). All development on iText 5 has stopped in favor of development on iText 7. New releases of iText 5 are made as a service *for customers who aren't ready to migrate to iText 7 yet.* New iText users should start with iText 7, **NOT** with iText 5!

Comment: @BrunoLowagie instead of downvoting, you can improve upon the answer already mentioned instead of providing another answer. That’s what stackoverflow is all about. Community, not personal gain.

Comment: I'll retract the down-vote if you update your answer. Please let me know when it's done by posting another comment mentioning my name. I am not here for personal gain. The gamification stopped working for me the moment I reached a 50K reputation (there are no more new privileges after 50K). Down-votes are used (and recommended) to mark bad answers. Your answer was promoting a version that wasn't future-proof instead of providing accurate information that was up-to-date. I hope you understand that's frustrating: it's very annoying for us to keep supporting a version that is outdated.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, update my answer with reference to itext7

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JAR download path. Click on below link to download JAR.

http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.13/itextpdf-5.5.13.jar

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to downvote this answer. iText 5.5.13 is a *maintenance* release of the old iText 5 version. The most recent version is [iText 7.1.2](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.itextpdf). All development on iText 5 has stopped in favor of development on iText 7. New releases of iText 5 are made as a service *for customers who aren't ready to migrate to iText 7 yet.* New iText users should start with iText 7, **NOT** with iText 5!

Answer (score -2):

The other answers to this question explain how to download iText 5. However, iText 5.5.13 is a *maintenance* release of the old iText 5 version. The most recent version is [iText 7.1.2](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.itextpdf). See also the official download page on the official web site: https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java

All development on iText 5 has stopped in favor of development on iText 7. New releases of iText 5 are made as a service *for customers who aren't ready to migrate to iText 7 yet.* New iText users should start with iText 7, **NOT** with iText 5!

**Source:** I am the original developer of iText, the founder, former CEO and current CTO of the iText companies.